# Программа на питон вычисляет средний балл неверно, почему?

Tags: python

```py
kol1=int(input("Введите количество 1:"))
kol2=int(input("Введите количество 2:"))
kol3=int(input("Введите количество 3:"))
kol4=int(input("Введите количество 4:"))
kol5=int(input("Введите количество 5:"))
sumkol = kol1+kol2+kol3+kol4+kol5 #сумма кол-ва оценок
sum2=2*kol2 #всего двоек
sum3=3*kol3 #всего троек
sum4=4*kol4 #всего четверок
sum5=5*kol5 #всего пятерок
print("Ваш средний бал:", kol1+sum2+sum3+sum4+sum5/sumkol)
```

P.S. Провела ход событий на обычном калькуляторе, все гладко, здесь в какой-то момент что-то идет не так.

Comment: Боюсь что вам надо математику подтянуть, `деление`(`/`) делается первым действием !!!

Comment: @maestro ** арифметику.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич ну математика более общее понятие, поэтому не имеет значения, только если для конкретизации

Answer (score 3):

```
(kol1+sum2+sum3+sum4+sum5)/sumkol
```

Вы забыли про скобочки. Операции сложения у Вас выполнялись уже после деления.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно поставить скобки вот так:

```
print("Ваш средний бал:", (kol1+sum2+sum3+sum4+sum5)/sumkol)
```

Answer (score 0):

`print("Ваш средний бал:", (kol1+sum2+sum3+sum4+sum5)/sumkol)`
Вы забыли поставить скобки, без них нарушается порядок действий